# Given stereo sound record, is there an algorithm extract the sound coming from a direction?

Tags: acoustics

Given a stereo record of music with singing (2 channels), subtract the left-channel waveform by the right-channel's, you might get the music only without the human singing.

The question is: can I, on the contrary, get the singing part only?

Comment: For future reference; this is more of a [signal processing question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/), and not so much a physics question.

Comment: You can get the sum and difference signals pretty easily.  What you can "extract" depends rather on what's in the L and R channels to begin with.

Comment: I think it's a physics problem - you have to think about wave propagation, plane waves vs spherical waves, etc.  (Sure in the simple stereo Left/Right problem, it is not so interesting, but this question hints at an entire field of interesting physics.)

Answer (score 1):

There are other instruments than are usually panned to the centre (eg Bass guitar, often drums) so those sounds are subtracted also. Karaoke functions found on some home stereos get around this by only cancelling the frequency range of the human voice which is not an ideal solution as many of the harmonics of other centre panned instruments also fall within this range.

If you were to invert a 'centre cancelled' waveform and add it to the original track the resulting waveform will be the centre only waveform which would (most probably) include the vocal part.

Another problem is that vocal tracks are often doubled (two 'takes' are recorded as identical as the vocalist can manage) and each take is panned slightly off centre to give a chorusing effect.

Answer (score 1):

Commercially-produced music recordings are often mixed artificially (i.e. by controlling the "levels" rather than simply using a stereo microphone), such that trying to spatially resolve the various audio sources may be impossible.

However, if you actually place a collection of microphones at different locations and record them all simultaneously, it is indeed possible - to some extent - to isolate sound waves coming from particular locations.  It's called a **[phased array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phased_array)**.

Here are several particular instances of this problem:

1. Locating gunshots in an urban environment.  Microphones placed on lamp-posts are all listening for gunshots.  When a gunshot is detected, it takes different amounts of time to travel to the various microphones, according to the distance from the source.  This can be 'inverted' to locate the source of the gunshot almost instantaneously by assuming that the sound coming from the gun spreads in as spherical (or at least circular) wavefront.
2. Identifying the direction to the source of a large, distant earthquake.  This works similarly, with a small cluster of seismometers (which are something like omnidirectional microphones).  By assuming a planar wavefront and using time-of-arrival information, the data can be 'inverted' to find the direction to the source.  Alternatively, the data from this group of seismometers can be combined in such a way that they 'listen' primarily for waves coming from a particular direction - say, an active fault or a location of suspected nuclear testing.  It's called "stacking" or "beamforming" or "synthetic beamforming".
3. Using multiple radio antennas to communicate with a particular WiFi access point while reducing interference from others.  The same idea; here it's called a phased array antenna.